How to Properly Use a Service to Lock the Screen with NgRx Signals? Is effect in Hooks the Right Place?
I’m working with NgRx Signals and trying to figure out the best way to utilize a ScreenLockService to lock/unlock the screen during specific operations. Below is my current setup using signalStore and a service for managing the screen lock:
export const BookStore = signalStore(
  withState(initialStore),
  withMethods((store,
               restService = inject(RestService)) => ({
    openModal: rxMethod<string>(
      pipe(
        tap(() => patchState(store, { isLoading: true })),
        switchMap((id) => {
          return from(restService.backendRestClient.getBook(id)).pipe(
            tapResponse({
              next: (books) => patchState(store, { books }),
              error: (err) => patchState(store, { error: err }),
              finalize: () => patchState(store, { isLoading: false })
            })
          );
        })
      )
    ),
  })),
  withHooks((store) => {
    const screenLockService = inject(ScreenLockService);

    return {
      onInit() {
        effect(() => {
          if (store.isLoading()) {
            screenLockService.lock();
          } else {
            screenLockService.unlock();
          }
        });
      },
    };
  })
);

My Questions:
Is using effect inside withHooks the correct approach for invoking screenLockService.lock() and unlock()?
Could there be a better way to handle this scenario, perhaps without coupling screen locking directly to the store state?
What I’m Considering:
Using the Store Outside of Hooks:
Should I move the screen lock logic to another service and subscribe to the store state changes there?
Alternative Patterns:
Could there be a more declarative or centralized way to manage side effects like screen locking when using signalStore?
Looking for insights or recommendations from the community! 
